# How to I insert a command into a script located on a remote server?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, remote, scripts

I want to insert `rm $0` in a script (`/home/user/config-script`) located on remote server with `echo "rm $0" >> /home/user/config-script` with `expect`. But fail because expect interprets `$0`.

```
var1="rm \$0"
expect -c 'spawn ssh user@192.168.1.200 ;expect "password" ; send "123456\n"; \
  expect "@"; send "sudo -k\n"; expect "@"; send "sudo su\n"; expect "password" ; \
  send "123456\n" ;expect "@"; send "echo '$var1'>>/home/user/config-script\n"; \
  expect "@"; send "exit\n"; send "logout\n"; interact'
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

---

```
missing "
    while executing
"send "echo rm"
couldn't read file "\$0>>/home/user/config-script\n"; expect "@"; send "exit\n"; send "logout\n"; interact": no such file or directory
```

In fact, on remote server I have an file called " /home/user/config-script".
Like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "my script"
```

finally, I want this script to be :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "my script"
rm $0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var1="rm \$0"` makes `var1` take on the value `rm $0`. Then `expect` tries to expand the `$0` when you run it.

To solve the problem, don't assign `var1` the value `rm $0`. Assign it a value that `expect` will expand to `rm $0`:

```
var1="rm \\\$0"
```

(Or equivalently: `var1='rm \$0'`)

This makes `var1` take on a value of `rm \$0` (which is perhaps what you had intended). Then the `send "echo '$var1'>>/home/user/config-script\n";` statement will cause the correct command to run on the remote machine:

```
echo 'rm $0'>>/home/user/config-script
```

---

The final result would look like the following:

```
var1='rm \\\$0'
expect -c 'spawn ssh user@192.168.1.200 ;expect "password" ; send "123456\n"; \
      expect "@"; send "sudo -k\n"; expect "@"; send "sudo su\n"; expect "password" ; \
      send "123456\n" ;expect "@"; send "echo '"$var1"'>>/home/user/config-script\n"; \
      expect "@"; send "exit\n"; send "logout\n"; interact'
```

Comment: I posted bellow so I can use the <code>

Comment: @georgian I'm guessing that means the "answer" you posted is a reply to this, detailing the error that occurred when you tried the method I suggested. (By the way, instead of posting an answer--unless you really have found the solution--you should instead edit your question. You can still comment on answers to notify their authors, of course, just as you did here.) I'll take a look...

Comment: you assumed correctly.

Comment: problem solved.   var1='rm \\\$0'    and   send "echo  '"$var1"'>> .   thanks